# Sympy fails to factorize to the maximum

Tags: python, sympy

I'm trying to simplify a matrix to inverse it after, but sympy doesn't factorize it as well as it could, which leads to unnecessary complicated expressions. Given that I'm working with big equations, I need them to be as simplified as possible, if not iPython just crashes.

Here is my code :

```
from sympy import *
from sympy.diffgeom import *
from __future__ import division
x, y, z, t = symbols('x y z t')
r, theta, phi = symbols('r \\theta \phi')
init_printing(use_latex=True)
m = Manifold('name', 4)
p = Patch('origin', m)
cart = CoordSystem('GP', p, ['t', 'x', 'y', 'z'])
t, x, y, z = cart.coord_functions()
dt, dx, dy, dz = cart.base_oneforms()
Rs, R = symbols('Rs R')
TP = TensorProduct
metric = (1-Rs/sqrt(x**2+y**2+z**2))*TP(dt,dt)-(1+x**2/(x**2+y**2+z**2)*(1-sqrt(x**2+y**2+z**2)/Rs)**-1)*TP(dx,dx)-(1+y**2/(x**2+y**2+z**2)*(1-sqrt(x**2+y**2+z**2)/Rs)**-1)*TP(dy,dy)-(1+z**2/(x**2+y**2+z**2)*(1-sqrt(x**2+y**2+z**2)/Rs)**-1+(x**2+y**2)/(x**2+y**2+z**2))*TP(dz,dz)-x*y/(x**2+y**2+z**2)*(1-sqrt(x**2+y**2+z**2)/Rs)**-1*(TP(dx,dy)+TP(dy,dx))-x*z/(x**2+y**2+z**2)*(1-sqrt(x**2+y**2+z**2)/Rs)**-1*(TP(dx,dz)+TP(dz,dx))-y*z/(x**2+y**2+z**2)*(1-sqrt(x**2+y**2+z**2)/Rs)**-1*(TP(dy,dz)+TP(dz,dy))
A = factor(twoform_to_matrix(metric)).subs({sqrt(x**2+y**2+z**2) : R, x**2+y**2+z**2 : R**2})
A
```

At this point, an example of what's wrong can be found at A.col(1)[1] : `(-R*x**2 - R*y**2 - R*z**2)` won't be factorized in `-R*(x**2+y**2+z**2)`, which I could in turn replace by `R**2` as I intend to.

I tried all built-in simplification methods of Sympy, but none of them did the trick.

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Comment: did you try to work without R, i.e. just putting in x^2+... from the start? Also you substitute R and R^2 which seems quite redundant, why did you add that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original op count of A as you have posted it is 157. After the following, it drops to 117:

```
>>> factor_terms(A).replace(lambda x: x.is_Add, lambda x: collect(x, (R, Rs)))
>>> _.count_ops()
117
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a solution to the question, just the output of the code of the OP. I hope this will help someone to answer the question.

```html
<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" display="block">
  <mrow>
    <mo>[</mo>
    <mtable rowspacing="4pt" columnspacing="1em">
      <mtr>
        <mtd>
          <mo>&#x2212;<!-- − --></mo>
          <mfrac>
            <mn>1</mn>
            <mi>R</mi>
          </mfrac>
          <mrow>
            <mo>(</mo>
            <mo>&#x2212;<!-- − --></mo>
            <mi>R</mi>
            <mo>+</mo>
            <mi>R</mi>
            <mi>s</mi>
            <mo>)</mo>
          </mrow>
        </mtd>
        <mtd>
          <mn>0</mn>
        </mtd>
        <mtd>
          <mn>0</mn>
        </mtd>
        <mtd>
          <mn>0</mn>
        </mtd>
      </mtr>
      <mtr>
        <mtd>
          <mn>0</mn>
        </mtd>
        <mtd>
          <mo>&#x2212;<!-- − --></mo>
          <mfrac>
            <mn>1</mn>
            <mrow>
              <msup>
                <mi>R</mi>
                <mrow class="MJX-TeXAtom-ORD">
                  <mn>2</mn>
                </mrow>
              </msup>
              <mrow>
                <mo>(</mo>
                <mo>&#x2212;<!-- − --></mo>
                <mi>R</mi>
                <mo>+</mo>
                <mi>R</mi>
                <mi>s</mi>
                <mo>)</mo>
              </mrow>
            </mrow>
          </mfrac>
          <mrow>
            <mo>(</mo>
            <mo>&#x2212;<!-- − --></mo>
            <mi>R</mi>
            <msup>
              <mrow class="MJX-TeXAtom-ORD">
                <mi mathvariant="bold">x</mi>
              </mrow>
              <mrow class="MJX-TeXAtom-ORD">
                <mn>2</mn>
              </mrow>
            </msup>
            <mo>&#x2212;<!-- − --></mo>
            <mi>R</mi>
            <msup>
              <mrow class="MJX-TeXAtom-ORD">
                <mi mathvariant="bold">y</mi>
              </mrow>
              <mrow class="MJX-TeXAtom-ORD">
                <mn>2</mn>
              </mrow>
            </msup>
            <mo>&#x2212;<!-- − --></mo>
            <mi>R</mi>
            <msup>
              <mrow class="MJX-TeXAtom-ORD">
                <mi mathvariant="bold">z</mi>
              </mrow>
              <mrow class="MJX-TeXAtom-ORD">
                <mn>2</mn>
              </mrow>
            </msup>
            <mo>+</mo>
            <mn>2</mn>
            <mi>R</mi>
            <mi>s</mi>
            <msup>
              <mrow class="MJX-TeXAtom-ORD">
                <mi mathvariant="bold">x</mi>
              </mrow>
              <mrow class="MJX-TeXAtom-ORD">
                <mn>2</mn>
              </mrow>
            </msup>
            <mo>+</mo>
            <mi>R</mi>
            <mi>s</mi>
            <msup>
              <mrow class="MJX-TeXAtom-ORD">
                <mi mathvariant="bold">y</mi>
              </mrow>
              <mrow class="MJX-TeXAtom-ORD">
                <mn>2</mn>
              </mrow>
            </msup>
            <mo>+</mo>
            <mi>R</mi>
            <mi>s</mi>
            <msup>
              <mrow class="MJX-TeXAtom-ORD">
                <mi mathvariant="bold">z</mi>
              </mrow>
              <mrow class="MJX-TeXAtom-ORD">
                <mn>2</mn>
              </mrow>
            </msup>
            <mo>)</mo>
          </mrow>
        </mtd>
        <mtd>
          <mo>&#x2212;<!-- − --></mo>
          <mfrac>
            <mrow>
              <mi>R</mi>
              <mi>s</mi>
              <mrow class="MJX-TeXAtom-ORD">
                <mi mathvariant="bold">x</mi>
              </mrow>
              <mrow class="MJX-TeXAtom-ORD">
                <mi mathvariant="bold">y</mi>
              </mrow>
            </mrow>
            <mrow>
              <msup>
                <mi>R</mi>
                <mrow class="MJX-TeXAtom-ORD">
                  <mn>2</mn>
                </mrow>
              </msup>
              <mrow>
                <mo>(</mo>
                <mo>&#x2212;<!-- − --></mo>
                <mi>R</mi>
                <mo>+</mo>
                <mi>R</mi>
                <mi>s</mi>
                <mo>)</mo>
              </mrow>
            </mrow>
          </mfrac>
        </mtd>
        <mtd>
          <mo>&#x2212;<!-- − --></mo>
          <mfrac>
            <mrow>
              <mi>R</mi>
              <mi>s</mi>
              <mrow class="MJX-TeXAtom-ORD">
                <mi mathvariant="bold">x</mi>
              </mrow>
              <mrow class="MJX-TeXAtom-ORD">
                <mi mathvariant="bold">z</mi>
              </mrow>
            </mrow>
            <mrow>
              <msup>
                <mi>R</mi>
                <mrow class="MJX-TeXAtom-ORD">
                  <mn>2</mn>
                </mrow>
              </msup>
              <mrow>
                <mo>(</mo>
                <mo>&#x2212;<!-- − --></mo>
                <mi>R</mi>
                <mo>+</mo>
                <mi>R</mi>
                <mi>s</mi>
                <mo>)</mo>
              </mrow>
            </mrow>
          </mfrac>
        </mtd>
      </mtr>
      <mtr>
        <mtd>
          <mn>0</mn>
        </mtd>
        <mtd>
          <mo>&#x2212;<!-- − --></mo>
          <mfrac>
            <mrow>
              <mi>R</mi>
              <mi>s</mi>
              <mrow class="MJX-TeXAtom-ORD">
                <mi mathvariant="bold">x</mi>
              </mrow>
              <mrow class="MJX-TeXAtom-ORD">
                <mi mathvariant="bold">y</mi>
              </mrow>
            </mrow>
            <mrow>
              <msup>
                <mi>R</mi>
                <mrow class="MJX-TeXAtom-ORD">
                  <mn>2</mn>
                </mrow>
              </msup>
              <mrow>
                <mo>(</mo>
                <mo>&#x2212;<!-- − --></mo>
                <mi>R</mi>
                <mo>+</mo>
                <mi>R</mi>
                <mi>s</mi>
                <mo>)</mo>
              </mrow>
            </mrow>
          </mfrac>
        </mtd>
        <mtd>
          <mo>&#x2212;<!-- − --></mo>
          <mfrac>
            <mn>1</mn>
            <mrow>
              <msup>
                <mi>R</mi>
                <mrow class="MJX-TeXAtom-ORD">
                  <mn>2</mn>
                </mrow>
              </msup>
              <mrow>
                <mo>(</mo>
                <mo>&#x2212;<!-- − --></mo>
                <mi>R</mi>
                <mo>+</mo>
                <mi>R</mi>
                <mi>s</mi>
                <mo>)</mo>
              </mrow>
            </mrow>
          </mfrac>
          <mrow>
            <mo>(</mo>
            <mo>&#x2212;<!-- − --></mo>
            <mi>R</mi>
            <msup>
              <mrow class="MJX-TeXAtom-ORD">
                <mi mathvariant="bold">x</mi>
              </mrow>
              <mrow class="MJX-TeXAtom-ORD">
                <mn>2</mn>
              </mrow>
            </msup>
            <mo>&#x2212;<!-- − --></mo>
            <mi>R</mi>
            <msup>
              <mrow class="MJX-TeXAtom-ORD">
                <mi mathvariant="bold">y</mi>
              </mrow>
              <mrow class="MJX-TeXAtom-ORD">
                <mn>2</mn>
              </mrow>
            </msup>
            <mo>&#x2212;<!-- − --></mo>
            <mi>R</mi>
            <msup>
              <mrow class="MJX-TeXAtom-ORD">
                <mi mathvariant="bold">z</mi>
              </mrow>
              <mrow class="MJX-TeXAtom-ORD">
                <mn>2</mn>
              </mrow>
            </msup>
            <mo>+</mo>
            <mi>R</mi>
            <mi>s</mi>
            <msup>
              <mrow class="MJX-TeXAtom-ORD">
                <mi mathvariant="bold">x</mi>
              </mrow>
              <mrow class="MJX-TeXAtom-ORD">
                <mn>2</mn>
              </mrow>
            </msup>
            <mo>+</mo>
            <mn>2</mn>
            <mi>R</mi>
            <mi>s</mi>
            <msup>
              <mrow class="MJX-TeXAtom-ORD">
                <mi mathvariant="bold">y</mi>
              </mrow>
              <mrow class="MJX-TeXAtom-ORD">
                <mn>2</mn>
              </mrow>
            </msup>
            <mo>+</mo>
            <mi>R</mi>
            <mi>s</mi>
            <msup>
              <mrow class="MJX-TeXAtom-ORD">
                <mi mathvariant="bold">z</mi>
              </mrow>
              <mrow class="MJX-TeXAtom-ORD">
                <mn>2</mn>
              </mrow>
            </msup>
            <mo>)</mo>
          </mrow>
        </mtd>
        <mtd>
          <mo>&#x2212;<!-- − --></mo>
          <mfrac>
            <mrow>
              <mi>R</mi>
              <mi>s</mi>
              <mrow class="MJX-TeXAtom-ORD">
                <mi mathvariant="bold">y</mi>
              </mrow>
              <mrow class="MJX-TeXAtom-ORD">
                <mi mathvariant="bold">z</mi>
              </mrow>
            </mrow>
            <mrow>
              <msup>
                <mi>R</mi>
                <mrow class="MJX-TeXAtom-ORD">
                  <mn>2</mn>
                </mrow>
              </msup>
              <mrow>
                <mo>(</mo>
                <mo>&#x2212;<!-- − --></mo>
                <mi>R</mi>
                <mo>+</mo>
                <mi>R</mi>
                <mi>s</mi>
                <mo>)</mo>
              </mrow>
            </mrow>
          </mfrac>
        </mtd>
      </mtr>
      <mtr>
        <mtd>
          <mn>0</mn>
        </mtd>
        <mtd>
          <mo>&#x2212;<!-- − --></mo>
          <mfrac>
            <mrow>
              <mi>R</mi>
              <mi>s</mi>
              <mrow class="MJX-TeXAtom-ORD">
                <mi mathvariant="bold">x</mi>
              </mrow>
              <mrow class="MJX-TeXAtom-ORD">
                <mi mathvariant="bold">z</mi>
              </mrow>
            </mrow>
            <mrow>
              <msup>
                <mi>R</mi>
                <mrow class="MJX-TeXAtom-ORD">
                  <mn>2</mn>
                </mrow>
              </msup>
              <mrow>
                <mo>(</mo>
                <mo>&#x2212;<!-- − --></mo>
                <mi>R</mi>
                <mo>+</mo>
                <mi>R</mi>
                <mi>s</mi>
                <mo>)</mo>
              </mrow>
            </mrow>
          </mfrac>
        </mtd>
        <mtd>
          <mo>&#x2212;<!-- − --></mo>
          <mfrac>
            <mrow>
              <mi>R</mi>
              <mi>s</mi>
              <mrow class="MJX-TeXAtom-ORD">
                <mi mathvariant="bold">y</mi>
              </mrow>
              <mrow class="MJX-TeXAtom-ORD">
                <mi mathvariant="bold">z</mi>
              </mrow>
            </mrow>
            <mrow>
              <msup>
                <mi>R</mi>
                <mrow class="MJX-TeXAtom-ORD">
                  <mn>2</mn>
                </mrow>
              </msup>
              <mrow>
                <mo>(</mo>
                <mo>&#x2212;<!-- − --></mo>
                <mi>R</mi>
                <mo>+</mo>
                <mi>R</mi>
                <mi>s</mi>
                <mo>)</mo>
              </mrow>
            </mrow>
          </mfrac>
        </mtd>
        <mtd>
          <mo>&#x2212;<!-- − --></mo>
          <mfrac>
            <mn>1</mn>
            <mrow>
              <msup>
                <mi>R</mi>
                <mrow class="MJX-TeXAtom-ORD">
                  <mn>2</mn>
                </mrow>
              </msup>
              <mrow>
                <mo>(</mo>
                <mo>&#x2212;<!-- − --></mo>
                <mi>R</mi>
                <mo>+</mo>
                <mi>R</mi>
                <mi>s</mi>
                <mo>)</mo>
              </mrow>
            </mrow>
          </mfrac>
          <mrow>
            <mo>(</mo>
            <mo>&#x2212;<!-- − --></mo>
            <mn>2</mn>
            <mi>R</mi>
            <msup>
              <mrow class="MJX-TeXAtom-ORD">
                <mi mathvariant="bold">x</mi>
              </mrow>
              <mrow class="MJX-TeXAtom-ORD">
                <mn>2</mn>
              </mrow>
            </msup>
            <mo>&#x2212;<!-- − --></mo>
            <mn>2</mn>
            <mi>R</mi>
            <msup>
              <mrow class="MJX-TeXAtom-ORD">
                <mi mathvariant="bold">y</mi>
              </mrow>
              <mrow class="MJX-TeXAtom-ORD">
                <mn>2</mn>
              </mrow>
            </msup>
            <mo>&#x2212;<!-- − --></mo>
            <mi>R</mi>
            <msup>
              <mrow class="MJX-TeXAtom-ORD">
                <mi mathvariant="bold">z</mi>
              </mrow>
              <mrow class="MJX-TeXAtom-ORD">
                <mn>2</mn>
              </mrow>
            </msup>
            <mo>+</mo>
            <mn>2</mn>
            <mi>R</mi>
            <mi>s</mi>
            <msup>
              <mrow class="MJX-TeXAtom-ORD">
                <mi mathvariant="bold">x</mi>
              </mrow>
              <mrow class="MJX-TeXAtom-ORD">
                <mn>2</mn>
              </mrow>
            </msup>
            <mo>+</mo>
            <mn>2</mn>
            <mi>R</mi>
            <mi>s</mi>
            <msup>
              <mrow class="MJX-TeXAtom-ORD">
                <mi mathvariant="bold">y</mi>
              </mrow>
              <mrow class="MJX-TeXAtom-ORD">
                <mn>2</mn>
              </mrow>
            </msup>
            <mo>+</mo>
            <mn>2</mn>
            <mi>R</mi>
            <mi>s</mi>
            <msup>
              <mrow class="MJX-TeXAtom-ORD">
                <mi mathvariant="bold">z</mi>
              </mrow>
              <mrow class="MJX-TeXAtom-ORD">
                <mn>2</mn>
              </mrow>
            </msup>
            <mo>)</mo>
          </mrow>
        </mtd>
      </mtr>
    </mtable>
    <mo>]</mo>
  </mrow>
</math>
```